# PHP read temperature values from local web server

Tags: php, parsing, file-get-contents

I am completely new to PHP.
I want to create a php page, which we will display a value from my local server,
which are given room temperature.

I try this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php

$homepage = file_get_contents('http://192.168.5.92/');
echo $homepage;
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout (
        function() { window.location.reload(); },
        2500
    )
</script>
```

I see entire page from my local Server.

But I want show only temperature, which is in square brackets.

Index.html from my local Server 192.168.5.92

```
Room1: [22.08] ° C 
Room2: [17.15] ° C 
Room3: [19.56] ° C
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: and what is your question? what did you tried? did you know preg_match functions?

Comment: If you get the content from your local server, wouldn't it make more sense to change the output there instead?

Comment: I only try "file_get_contents"

Comment: I have 4 local server and with new page i want to merge all temperature values into one page.

Comment: I want from new page :

Comment: 1. read text from url:192.168.5.92, 2. write text (value) behind text "Room1: "

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $temp1 = "Room1: [22.08] ° C";
    $newTemp = substr($temp,8,5);
    echo $newTemp;
    // OUTPUT : 22.08
?>
```

By using this method you will only get the temprature between the brackets

Comment: ?? This not work...
I get the value 22.08.... always :)
I want to read value on local server 192.168.5.92
Room1: [XX.YY] ° C   

XX and YY it changes....
Any more suggestions?

Comment: Can you not change the information that te local server send's to the page when you read the file. There must be some variable that you send or return to get that result. Can you maybe include the code from the local server that get's the tempratures?

Comment: I change room etc... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the index.html then use the following code

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://192.168.5.92/");
$values = explode("° C", $var);
array_pop($values);
foreach($values as $row){
  $temp = explode(":",$row);
  $temperature[] = $temp[1]. "° C";
}
print_r($temperature);  //Array ( [0] => [22.08] ° C [1] => [17.15] ° C [2] => [19.56] ° C )
```

Answer (score 0):

I little change your code and now i see:

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://192.168.5.92/");
$values = explode("]", $var);
array_pop($values);
foreach($values as $row){
  $temp = explode("[",$row);
  $temperature[] = $temp[1]. "° C";
}
print_r($temperature); 




 Array ( [0] => -3.00 ° C [1] => 87.31 ° C [2] => 51.19 ° C [3] => 46.19 ° C [4] => 49.38 ° C [5] => 5.00 ° C )
```

Fine, at least one success...

No i want every value in new row. and without "Array ( [0] =>" 
It is not possible to print the value after words example "ROOM1: " ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <center>
    <H1>
    Heading:
    <H1>
    <font color=black size=7><br />
    <font color=black size=7>Outside temp.:[-3.00] &#176;
    C
    <font color=black size=7><br />
    <font color=black size=7>Stove: [82.87] &#176;
    C
    <font color=black size=7><br />
    <font color=black size=7>Supply: [51.69] &#176;
    C
    <font color=black size=7><br />
    <font color=black size=7>Return: [46.25] &#176;
    C
    <font color=black size=7><br />
    <font color=black size=7>Water: [49.38] &#176;
    C
    <font color=black size=7><br />
    <font color=black size=7>DIFF: [5.44] &#176;
    C
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);   
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
$arduino92 = file_get_contents("http://192.168.5.92/");
$stove = get_string_between($arduino92, "Stove: [", "]");
echo "Stove: $stove"."<br>";
```

problem solved!
Regards